# can't ping from mac host to windows guest in virtual box

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtualbox, osx-yosemite

I am trying to ping to the windows 7 guest in virtual machine from mac host. but I get below message

```
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
```

I set bridged-network in network setting and turned off firewalls in windows machine with no luck. I have installed yosemite in mac. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: What IP addresses do the host and guest have? What address are you actually trying to ping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by following the steps below.

1. Created a host-only adapter by going to setting of virtual machine as below

[image: windows 7 virtual machine virtual box settings]

2. Check the first three decimal parts of windows 7 virtual machine ip address

   ex : It is 192.168.56 in my case

[image]

3. Go to virtual box -> Preferences -> Network. Select the host-only Networks tab. click the edit button. Change the first three decimal parts of IPv4 address of Adapter tab as in windows 7 virtual machine ip address.

[image: edit settings of host-only adapter]

Now you should be able to ping guest windows 7 from host mac.

Answer (score 1):

Check the network profile. In Windows 7 you have a firewall for each network profile.

- Control Panel -> System and Security -> Windows Firewall

Comment: Since the OP mentioned he turned off firewalls, and since there is a `No route to host` reported; this suggestion would perhaps be better provided as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are circumstances under which Windows 7 will not respond to a ping request.

These include:

> From time to time there is an issue with Windows 7 computers in the network: they do not answer ping requests although everything seems properly configured and other clients in the same network work fine.
>
> This is because only clients with activated “File and Printer Sharing” do answer ping requests by default.

https://marcowuen.wordpress.com/2012/09/15/solved-windows-7-client-ignores-ping-requests/

At other times, they do not respond because the onboard security software does not allow for it as well (you can't hack what does't exist. Security through obscurity.)

There are times when configuration issues can cause performance issues which can manifest themselves as time out difficulties. These include setup of IPv6 and sub-par drivers.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-to-enable-ping-response-in-windows-7/5aff5f8d-f138-4c9a-8646-5b3a99f1cae6

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/windows-7-not-respond-to-ping-even-enabled/bbfe6c95-bd95-40ae-876a-34e82af1fe12

[Online computer not responding to pings](https://superuser.com/questions/766404/online-computer-not-responding-to-pings)